# Find $n + 1$ vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$ that are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ over  $\mathbb{R}$ with usual operations.

Find $n + 1$ vectors in  $\mathbb{C}^n$ that are linearly independent over  $\mathbb{R}$

My attempts: I know that  every real number is  a complex number... so  we  can not finds $n + 1$ vectors in  $\mathbb{C}^n$ that are linearly independent over  $\mathbb{R}$   Because  if the $n$ vectors are linearly independent then they are the full set of a basis and the remaining one will surely be a spanned by the other $n$ elements.

Is it True/false?

Any Hints/solution will be appreaciated

thanks in advance

Comment: $\mathbb C$ is a $2$ dimensional space over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^n$ is $n$-dimensional over $\mathbb{C}$ but actually $2n$-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$. For instance, in the case $n=1$, an $\mathbb{R}$-basis of $\mathbb{C}$ is given by the two vectors $1$ and $i$.

Comment: thanks @lulu..,,

Comment: thanks u @Suzet

Comment: Consider the case $n = 1$, i.e. $V = \mathbb{C}$. Try to make an argument for the fact that you cannot scale the number $1$ by any real number $\lambda$ to obtain $\lambda \cdot 1 = i$ (it boils down to the fact that $1$ is the multiplicative identity and $i$ is not a real number). Therefore the 'vectors' $1$ and $i$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Now generalize for any $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the standard basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and add $f=(i,0,0,\ldots,0)$ to it. If $\alpha_1e_1+\cdots\alpha_n e_n+\alpha_{n+1}f=0$, with all $\alpha_k$'s real, then$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\alpha_1+\alpha_{n+1}i=0\\\alpha_2=0\\\alpha_3=0\\\vdots\\\alpha_n=0\end{array}\right.$$Therefore, all $\alpha_k$'s are equal to $0$:

Comment: im not getting as  i   take  $e_1,e_2,........,e_n$  basis of $ \mathbb{C^n}$,,,,how  can  we  add ,,,and show that .....Can u  elaborate more  @ Jose  carlos sir

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: thanks a lots @Jose carlos santos

Answer (score 2):

You can remember that $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ is isomorphic to  $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ so you can definitely find n+1  $\mathbb{R}$ independent vectors in  $\mathbb{C}^{n}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are looking for n+1 vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$ not in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Since $\mathbb{C}^n$ is a $2n$ dimensional space over $\mathbb{R}$, there are many such vectors in  $\mathbb{C}^n$

Comment: thanks  u @Mohammad Riazi-kermani